# how to generate python codes with wxFormBuilder?

Tags: python, wxformbuilder

I created a simple form(frame) with buttons in wxBuilderForm.

When I generate codes (when pressing F8 in wxFormBuilder), it generates the following three files:

```
noname.cpp
noname.h
test1.fbp
```

If I compare to a template that I downloaded and which contains the following files..:

```
gui.fbp
gui.py
gui.pyc
main.py
MainFrame.py
MainFrame.pyc
```

I wonder why I can not generate (by pressing F* in wxFormBuilder) Python files?

Answer (score 3):

Actually I believe the correct method is to set the project properties such that the 'code_generation' property is set to Python. Also you will need to provide a value for the 'file' property or else you will continue to get files named 'noname'.

You should be able to access your project's properties by selecting the root node in the Object Tree.

Answer (score 1):

never mind folks.

It was super simple.

There is a tag at the bottom named python. This is where you get the codes.

Answer (score 1):

To change generate code to Python from the default C++, just click on the project at the top of your project tree on the left. Then under object properties on the right, you will be able to choose the languages you want to output to under the 'code_generation' setting and the file name can be changed in the 'file' setting. It will add a .py extension by default.